# After succesfull merge of pull request on github commit dissapier

Tags: git, github

After succesfull merge of pull request on github a commit  dissapear with code.

In github it looks like this:[image]
merge commit has number and two parents, but in tree there are no merge commit at all:[image]

And also now github say that two branches are at one (feature/OLFU-8334 and feature/OLFU-8471):
[image]

How it can be? I need to know to prevent such strange behaviour in future.

Comment: Your question contains far too little information about the repositories and the histories before and after the merge to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the manual hard change to git history.

Answer (score 0):

There is way too little information too provided a good answer. But the merge has most likely ended as a fast-forward merge.

Comment: And how he disappeared? There are no changes from that merge in branch, and there are not revert commit.

What additional information do you need?